# Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `loadedData` while in state rootState.loaded.updated.uncommitted

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember-data to fetch data from a REST API and have created a model App.Category. In the 'index' state, I fetch data this way:

```
App.Category.find({type: 1});
```

That works fine. However, whenever I transition to a new state and call:

```
App.Category.find({type: 2});
```

However, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `loadedData` on <App.Category:ember424:1> while in state rootState.loaded.updated.uncommitted. Called with {}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Found that I was updating the record in an obscure part of my code. Problem solved

Comment: Would it be possible to remove this question ?

Answer (score 3):

I recently hit this problem, the root cause was I was doing something silly like not rendering  a JSON representation of the updated model.

Here is an example of what I was rendering from a rails controller on update:

`format.json { head status: :ok }`

Here is how I fixed it:

`format.json { render json: @thing, status: :ok }`

Comment: I would agree, I had it because I was referencing invalid data in my fixtures.